# inherit from a class constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm learning javscript and trying to know more about object oriented programming.

i have a class called `man`:

```
var man = function() {

    this.name = "jack";

    this.walk = function(){
        console.log("im walking");
    };

};
```

i want create another class called `hero` that inherits from `man` containing all `man` class methods and properties

```
var hero = function(){

 // inherit from man and has it own methods

};
```

How to do that so i can create object contain methods from both of them.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (and outside of) the hero function assign `new man()` to hero's `prototype`:

```js
var man = function() {

    this.name = "jack";

    this.walk = function() {
        console.log("im walking");
    };
};

var hero = function() {
    // hero stuff
}

hero.prototype = new man();

// ...

var batman = new hero();

alert(batman.name) // jack
```

Comment: No, [don't use `new man()` for creating the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!

Comment: i think 
var hero = function() {
    
man.call(this)
}

was the right answer why you change it ?